# I can't deploy my php app to Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

This is the first time I get in touch with Heroku (it's really amazing).
I followed these steps to deploy my very first app to heroku.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'
heroku create abcfirstapp
git remote add origin git@heroku.com:abcfirstapp.git
git push heroku master
```

And I got the error like

> Heroku push rejected, no Cedar--supported app detected
>   To git@heroku.com:abcfirstapp.git
>   [remote.rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:abcfirstapp.git'

I'm quite sure that my php file is written probably since it runs well with my local xampp server

```
<?PHP phpinfo(); ?>
```

One more problem is: when I try to pull from heroku using

```
git pull heroku master
```

I got an error

> fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

Could anyone help me out please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default PHP buildpack detects PHP apps by [looking for](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/detect) `index.php` in the repo root. Do you have one of those?

Alternatively, you can hardcode the buildpack:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
```

Comment: hi, it's really helpful. Btw, can you explain to me the purpose of having the index.php and how the index.php looks like.

Comment: When Heroku gets your app source code, it has to decide what buildpack to use when building your app slug (i.e. Ruby, Python, something else). To detect whether to use the PHP buildpack (which is what you want), it looks for the existence of a file called `index.php` since most PHP apps will tend to have that.

Answer (score 2):

> no Cedar--supported app detected

PHP is not a natively supported language on Heroku, outside of Facebook apps I suppose. You'll need to utilize something like a [Third Party Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the docs (Apr 2015) recommend you set a custom buildpack via:

`heroku buildpack:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Answer (score 0):

What is required is at least an empty `composer.json` push this, and re-deploy